# OPSHUB_ERROR on Migration TFS On Premise to VSTS

Tags: migration, azure-devops, opshub

I was trying to migrate a VS Project from TFS 2013 on Premise to Visual Studio Team Services. Unfortunately i had an issue:

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF10131: The workspace name
>   OH_6_14572940012671457294001269-Diego Italo Castillo Castillo87664
>   contains more than 64 characters, contains one of the following
>   characters: "/:<>\|*?; or ends with a space.  Type a valid name and
>   try again.

I was trying to migrate a project (Source Code Only) for about 8 hours and i was getting the error in an specific Changueset.

I cant find the real problem.
I Attached logs.

[image: Image Descripcion]
Logs: http://1drv.ms/1paQKu0

Comment: Workspace that the tool is trying to create used username and some random keys. The resultant name character count is exceeding the permissible limit, A quick solution would be to 1. Close utility 2. Open Visual Studio 3. Connect to your target system 4. Under Source Control Explorer > Workspace (Select Box) > Delete all workspaces starting with name OH_X_XXXX (Where X is a number) 5. Restart the utility.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. I've changed my credentials Name (Shortly) in my Microsoft Account I was using in order to connect with my VSTS repository.